# An enhanced syntax for defining functions in PostScript

Tags: postscript

This file enhances PostScript with a few new syntactic niceties for defining functions with named arguments and even type-checking.

### block

The first part of the enhancement consists of a new control structure called a "block". A block is a list of pairs which will be collected as key/value pairs into a dictionary and then the special key `main` gets called. This much allows us to elide the 'def' for all functions and data, and also the `/` decorations on all the function names.

```
{
    main { f g h }
    f { }
    g { }
    h { }
} block
```

This code defines a `main` function and 3 functions that `main` calls. When `block` executes, all 4 functions are defined in a dictionary and then `main` gets called.

Importantly, it lets you put `main` at the top to aid top-down coding. Alternatively, there is a function `pairs-begin` which can be used with this same array of pairs as an upgrade to the traditional `<< ... >> begin` construct.

### func

Another enhancement is the `func` syntax. A function can be created to accept named arguments by calling `func` with the array of argument names and the array of the body of the function. To do this within the `block` construct where normally the contents of the block are not executed but just collected, you can force execution by prefixing the `@` sign to `func`. Any name can be executed "at compile time" with this `@` prefix, but only at the top-level.

Using `func` you can give names to the arguments of functions by enclosing them in curly braces before the function body:

```
{
    main{
        3 f
        4 5 g
    }
    f {x}{ 1 x div sin } @func
    g {x y}{ x log y log mul } @func
} block
```

This code creates a function `f` of one argument `x`, and a function `g` of two arguments `x` and `y`. The function body is augmented with code which takes these 2 objects from the stack and defines them in a new local dictionary created and `begin`ed for this invocation of the function, coupled with an `end` at the end.

For some use cases like implementing control structures, it is useful to place the `end` more strategically. The `fortuple` function illustrates this by using `@func-begin` which does not add `end` at the end. It then places the `end` earlier, before calling back to the p argument.

A function can also declare the types that its arguments must have by enclosing them in parentheses and using executable names for the argument names and literal names for the types:

```
{
    main {
        3 4 p
    }
    p (x/integer y/integer){ x y add } @func
} block
```

This augments the function body with code which checks that there are indeed enough objects on the stack, or else it triggers a `stackunderflow` error. Then it checks that all of the arguments have the expected type, or else it triggers a `typecheck` error. The types here are written without the letters `type` at the end; these are added automatically.

You can omit the type name with the parenthesized syntax and it will allow any type for that argument. If you omit all the type names you still get the `stackunderflow` checking. With any of these errors the name of the user function is reported in the error message for easier debugging.

### Implementation

Implementation-wise, the foundation is the `pairs` construct which is an array which gets traversed with `forall`. Any name beginning with `@` gets the `@` stripped off and the remainder gets executed. The results are enclosed in `<<` and `>>` to create a dictionary.

The first dictionary defines everything to do with `pairs` including `pairs-def` which adds the key/value pairs into the current dictionary rather than begin a new dictionary. The next two sections add their functions to this same dictionary.

This justifies (somewhat) the cuddled style of bracing. The whole implementation is split into 3 layers but the result is only 1 dictionary on the dictstack with all of these functions in it.

The middle section defines `block` and `func` and all of the functionality for the `simple-func` style of defining functions. The third section implements two looping control structures which use the `simple-func` style. These looping functions are then used by the more complex `typed-func` style.

Many of the functions used to implement all of this are useful in their own right so they are also supplied to the user, like `curry` `compose` `reduce`.

There is some simplistic testing code at the bottom guarded by `/debug where`. So if this file is simply `run` from another file, it will skip the testing code. But if the key `debug` is defined somewhere on the dictstack, then the testing code will execute. So with ghostscript, testing can be invoked with `gs -ddebug struct2.ps`.

The testing code itself illustrates the overhead of the code added by `func`. For type checking, it adds a fair amount of code.

```
%!
% struct2.ps   An enhanced PostScript syntax for defining functions with named,
% type-checked arguments. Using @func within a block or other construct that uses
% 'pairs' accomplishes a sort of compile-time macro expansion of the shorthand function description.
<<
    /pairs-begin { pairs begin        }
    /pairs-def   { pairs {def} forall }
    /pairs       { << exch explode >> }
    /explode     { { @exec } forall   }
    /@exec       { dup type /nametype eq { exec-if-@ } if }
    /exec-if-@   { dup dup length string cvs dup first (@) first eq { exec@ }{ pop } ifelse }
    /first       { 0 get }            /exec@ {  exch pop rest cvn cvx exec  }
    /rest        { 1 1 index length 1 sub getinterval }
>> begin {
    block { pairs-begin main end }
    func  { 1 index type /stringtype eq { typed-func }{ simple-func } ifelse }
    simple-func { func-begin { end } compose }
    typed-func  { exch args-and-types reverse { make-type-name } map check-stack 3 1 roll
                  exch simple-func   compose }
    func-begin  { exch reverse /args-begin load curry exch compose }
    args-begin  { dup length dict begin { exch def } forall }
    args-and-types { /was_x false def [ exch { each-specifier } fortokens fix-last ] dup args exch types  }
    each-specifier { dup xcheck /is_x exch def  is_x was_x and { null exch } if  /was_x is_x def }
    fix-last       { counttomark 2 mod 1 eq { null } if }
    check-stack    { {pop} 4 index cvlit { cvx /stackunderflow signalerror } curry compose
                     /if cvx 2 array astore cvx {check-count} exch compose curry
                     3 index cvlit { cvx /typecheck signalerror } curry
                     /if cvx 2 array astore cvx {check-types} exch compose compose }
    check-count { dup length count 2 sub gt }
    check-types { dup length 1 add copy true exch { check-type and } forall exch pop not }
    check-type  { dup null eq { 3 -1 roll pop pop true }{ 3 -1 roll type eq } ifelse }
    make-type-name { dup type /nametype eq { dup length 4 add string dup dup 4 2 roll cvs
                     2 copy 0 exch putinterval length (type) putinterval cvn } if }
    args    { [ exch 2 { 0 get } fortuple ] }
    types   { [ exch 2 { 1 get } fortuple ] }
    map     { 1 index xcheck 3 1 roll  [ 3 1 roll forall ]  exch {cvx} if }
    reduce  { exch dup first exch rest 3 -1 roll forall }
    rreduce { exch aload length 1 sub dup 3 add -1 roll repeat }
    curry   { [ 3 1 roll {} forall ] cvx } @pop
            { dup length 1 add array dup 0 5 -1 roll put dup 1 4 -1 roll putinterval cvx }
    compose { 2 array astore cvx { {} forall } map } @pop
            { 1 index length 1 index length add array  dup 0 4 index putinterval
              dup 4 -1 roll length 4 -1 roll putinterval cvx }
    reverse { [ exch dup length 1 sub -1 0 { 2 copy get 3 1 roll pop } for pop ] }
} pairs-def {
    fortokens {src proc}{ { src token {exch /src exch store}{exit}ifelse  proc } loop } @func
    fortuple {a n p}{ 0 n /a load length 1 sub
        { /a exch /n getinterval /p exec } {load-if-literal-name} map end for
    } @func-begin
    load-if-literal-name { dup type /nametype eq 1 index xcheck not and { load } if }
} pairs-def

/debug where{pop}{currentfile flushfile}ifelse
{
    - sub + add * mul    %:= {exch def}    += {dup load 3 -1 roll + store}

    var 2 3 @add

    
    f  {x y z}{ x  y z +  *      } @func

    f' {x y z}{ x  y z +  *  end } @func-begin

    f'' { {z y x}args-begin  x y z + *  end }

    
    g(x/integer y/integer z/real){ x y z + * } @func

    g' {
        [/realtype/integertype/integertype]
        check-count { pop /g cvx /stackunderflow signalerror } if
        check-types { /g cvx /typecheck signalerror } if

        {z y x}args-begin  x y z + *  end
    }

    
    h(x y z){ x y z + * } @func %@dup @==

    h' {
        [null null null]
        check-count { pop /h cvx /stackunderflow signalerror } if
        check-types { /h cvx /typecheck signalerror } if

        {z y x}args-begin  x y z + *  end
    }

    
    main {
        var ==
        [ 1 2 3 4 5 ] { - } rreduce ==
        / =
        3 4 5 f ==
        3 4 5 f' ==
        3 4 5 f'' ==
        / =
        3 4 5.0 g =
        3 4 5.0 g' =
        { 3 4 5 g = } stopped { $error /errorname get =only ( in ) print $error /command get = } if
        / =
        clear
        { 3 4 h  = } stopped { $error /errorname get =only ( in ) print $error /command get = } if
        clear
        3 4 5 h =
        { 3.0 4.0 5.0 h = } stopped { $error /errorname get =only ( in ) print $error /command get = } if
        { 3.0 4.0 5.0 h' = } stopped { $error /errorname get =only ( in ) print $error /command get = } if
        quit
    }

} block
```

The output from the testing code:

```
$ gsnd -q -ddebug struct2.ps
5
3

27
27
27

27.0
27.0
typecheck in g

stackunderflow in h
27
27.0
27.0
```

Are there improvements to make to the implementation or the behavior? Currently the `simple-func` style does not check that there are enough arguments but just tries to define them assuming that they're there. Would it be better to add this checking, or is it better to have this low-overhead version which does not add (possibly wasteful) checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function

```
check-stack    { {pop} 4 index cvlit { cvx /stackunderflow signalerror } curry compose
                 /if cvx 2 array astore cvx {check-count} exch compose curry
                 3 index cvlit { cvx /typecheck signalerror } curry
                 /if cvx 2 array astore cvx {check-types} exch compose compose }
```

is a mess. It would probably be better written in a template instantiation style.

```
check-stack  { % types -> stack-checker-proc-for-types
  {_types _args _body _name} args-begin
  /_name load /_name 1 index cvlit def
  /_body load /_args load
  ({
    //_types
    check-count { pop //_name cvx /stackunderflow signalerror } if
    check-types { //_name cvx /typecheck signalerror } if
  }) cvx exec
  end
}
```